# Can a java compiler optimize this code away?

Tags: java, optimization, dead-code, unreachable-code

Is a java compiler or runtime ( or any other language compiler ) smart enough to realize branch 3 can never happen , and optimize it away?  I've seen this kind of "defensive programming" with many beginning developers, and wonder if this dead weight stays in the bytecode.

```
import java.util.Random;


class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = new Random().nextInt() % 10;
        if ( x < 5 )
        {
            System.out.println("Case 1");
        }
        else
            if ( x >= 5 )
            {
                System.out.println("Case 2");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Case 3");
            }

    }
}
```

or even this more blunt case

```
boolean bool = new Random().nextBoolean();
if ( bool )
{
    System.out.println("Case 1");
}
else
    if ( bool )
    {
        System.out.println("Case 2");
    }
```

Comment: A JITC might figure it out.  Or at the very least would figure out from profiling that it was extremely rare and so somehow optimize the tests and move the actual code out of line.  (It would be very unusual for javac to optimize it away.)

Comment: Side point: Do call `nextInt(n)` rather than `nextInt() % n`. It handles various tricky cases. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)

Answer (score 4):

The Java 8 compiler I have doesn't seem to optimize it away.  Using "javap -c"  to examine the byte code after compiling:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class java/util/Random
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/util/Random."<init>":()V
       7: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/util/Random.nextInt:()I
      10: bipush        10
      12: irem
      13: istore_1
      14: iload_1
      15: iconst_5
      16: if_icmpge     30
      19: getstatic     #5                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      22: ldc           #6                  // String Case 1
      24: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      27: goto          54
      30: iload_1
      31: iconst_5
      32: if_icmplt     46
      35: getstatic     #5                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      38: ldc           #8                  // String Case 2
      40: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      43: goto          54
      46: getstatic     #5                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      49: ldc           #9                  // String Case 3
      51: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      54: return
}
```

The string "Case 3" still exists in the byte code.

Comment: Javac never optimize such things. It's a JIT compiler job.

Comment: @leventov the JIT won't remove the dead code though, it just sits there.  That said, its also not doing anything other than just sitting there.  There are no significant time optimizations that one would gain removing it (if it could be detected).